# Laravel : Tracking visitors info

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an application created using `React` and `Laravel`.
In my application each user have multiple pages.

I would want to display to the users the statistics of the visitors of their pages, like number of visitors, devices, countries etc..

This service summers perfectly what I would want to achieve https://11uptime.com/ & https://11uptime.com/assets/images/screenshots/webp/status-page-a.webp

As you can see each page have it own statistics displayed to the user.

So far I found [tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) for Laravel who tracks the informations of the visitors.
**How can I track the visitors and display their data to the user according to the visited page ?**

So when the user check his created page, he will see statistics of the people who visited that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) to track your app traffic and use [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4) to display Google Analytics data on your custom dashboard.

Comment: So I will have a custom API that I can display according to some conditions in the Frontend ?

Comment: I mean your solution seems very helpful, but I doubt I can show to a specific users the information of his visitors. Because there will be no user_id in that api, I might be wrong.

Comment: @AlyaKra Yes, you can set specific properties (like `user_id`) on each page for Google Analytics and later filter the collected data based on that property. here is the ref: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en

Comment: Very interesting. And if I had to retrieve the API I would be using React for that right ? As I don't see the utility of Laravel in your solution.

Comment: @AlyaKra You may use it's [PHP client library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) on server side or [JavaScript client library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js) on client side.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna use it in React I guess. But it appears very challenging for me. I will try my best. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Extracting Client IP Address
$client = request()->ip();

// Initializing Variables
$country = "Unknown";
$city = "Unknown";
$latitude = "Unknown";
$longitude = "Unknown";

// Validating IP Address
if (filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    $ip = $client;
} elseif (filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    $ip = $forward;
} else {
    $ip = $remote;
}

// Retrieving Geolocation Data
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$ip_data_in = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Parsing Geolocation Data
$ip_data = json_decode($ip_data_in, true);
$ip_data = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $ip_data);

// Extracting Geolocation Information
if ($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'] != NULL) {
    $country = $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'];
}
if ($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_city'] != NULL) {
    $city = $ip_data['geoplugin_city'];
}
if ($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_latitude'] != NULL) {
    $latitude = $ip_data['geoplugin_latitude'];
}
if ($ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_longitude'] != NULL) {
    $longitude = $ip_data['geoplugin_longitude'];
}

// Tracking Visitor Information
$uris = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uris = $uris . '/';
$amit = explode('/', $uris, -1);
$count = count($amit);
$url = $amit[$count - 1];
if ($url == '') {
    $url = 'home';
}

$abc = Visitor::where('ip', $ip)
    ->where('latitude', $latitude)
    ->where('longitude', $longitude)
    ->where('country', $country)
    ->where('slug', $url)
    ->first();

// Here, you can perform further actions or store the visitor data
// based on the extracted information.
```